# Unit Testing linked to a binary framework

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I am trying to build an application using 2 frameworks : 1 is already compiled, and the other is a normal target of my project. I can make the application run but I am struggling to run Unit Tests. I created a dummy project with 3 elements to simplify things:

Framework 1 containing only one class:

```
public class DummyClassFramework1{
    public static func helloWorld()-> String {
        return "Hello from Framework 1"
    }
}
```

Framework 2 containing only one class:

```
import Framework1
public class DummyClassFramework2{
    public static func helloWorld()-> String {
        return DummyClassFramework1.helloWorld() //Calling a class from framework1
    }
}
```

The demo App using this view controller:

```
import Framework2
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(DummyClassFramework2.helloWorld())
    }
}
```

When I put everything in the same project, everything work: testing framework1, testing framework2, testing the app. However when I generate a fat framework1 with lipo, copy the .framework file in a new project that contains framework2 and demo App: I can not test framework 2 nor the demo App. However I can run the app normally.

The error that i get when launching tests is :

2018-09-13 11:51:04.645977+0200 xctest[34017:587268] The bundle “Framework1” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I actually found the solution by myself:

Go in the target Framework2Test -> General -> Testing -> choose demo App in Host Application.

Since the demo App is already embedding the binary framework, the test will run smoothly